# How can I divide an integer by an integer in C# and have a variable that has one or more decimal places?

Tags: c#

I tried this:

```
var b = 100 / 95;
```

and b is declared as an integer.  But I would like to have a number with a decimal point.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Just googled "int by int division C#" and immediately found a dozens duplicate.

Comment: var b = 100d / 95d;

Comment: Is this some kind of reputation enhancing scheme? Ask easily googleable question, let mates answer it, give reputation to mates?

Comment: Maybe I am too suspicious but I don't buy making such a basic and duplicated question with 1400 rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With two integer operands, the C# overload resolution picks a version of the division operator that does integer division.

To make C# choose real division, you need to change the type of at least one of the operands into `decimal`, `float`, or `double`.

You can achieve this by casting, in the general case. In your specific case, you can also just change the literals involved:

```
 var b = 100m / 95;   // decimal
 var b = 100f / 95;   // float
 var b = 100.0 / 95;  // double
```

Use `decimal` if these are exact, human-made quantities (e.g. money). Use `float` or `double` if you are dealing with approximate, physical quantities (e.g. irrational numbers, physical constants, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an integer division which will ignore the fractional part of the division as it can not be stored in an `int`.

If you cast your variables to `decimal`s you can store the fractional part of the division:

```
decimal b = (decimal)100 / (decimal)95;
```